# How to select and copy text from FlowTextView in android

Tags: android

I am having flowtextview that flows around the image.I want to select the text on long touch ..How can i do that for the flow text view ..What i have done so far is

```
txtDesc = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.tDescription);
txtDesc.setText(temp_desc);
CharSequence stringYouExtracted = text.getText();
int startIndex = text.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = text.getSelectionEnd();
stringYouExtracted = ( stringYouExtracted).subSequence(startIndex, endIndex);
getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) 
{
   android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
} else {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  System.err.println("clipboard to select"+clipboard);
}
```

Comment: Have you found the answer? Or whether it is even possible...